# CakePHP 3 How to detect if an entity field is changed

Tags: cakephp, entity

I'm developing a CakePHP 3 application.

Now, i need to encrypt some data with SHA1 before the save of the entity.

I tried the beforeSave() callback in Table Object, like in CakePHP 2.x, but it doesn't work.

So, i discovered that type of change (update data on beforeSave/beforeUpdate) in current version, needs to be adapted to accessors & mutators, like the docs says (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators).

Documentation even has a note about check if an entity field was modified (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#checking-if-an-entity-has-been-modified) but i dont understand how to use this.

I need some simple logic, just like an authentication system.

Before Save, in User Model, the field `responsible_card_password` must be hashed with SHA1 if this is filled. If isnt filled, the field stays the same.

Currently, with the acessors and mutators method, if i put the field on form blank, the entity save this field blank.

How i can solve this? Very thanks CakePHP developers on the world! :-D

Answer (score 0):

you can add code in your entity table to auto hashing password

```
protected function _setPassword($password)
{
    return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}
```